# what if I delete the pointer that the smart pointer is managing?

Tags: c++, pointers, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I read the smart pointer from *C++ Primer 5 Edition*. In section 12.1.3, some description goes like

> The smart pointer types define a function named 'get' that returns a built-in pointer to the object that the smart pointer is managing. The function is intended for cases when we need to pass a built-in pointer to code that can't use a smart pointer. **The code that uses the return from 'get' must not 'delete' that pointer.**

A example is also given below the description

```
shared_ptr<int> p(new int(42));       // reference count is 1
int *q = p.get();
{//new block
//undefined:two independent shared_ptr point to the same memory
      shared_ptr<int>(q);
}//block ends, q is destroyed ,and the memory to which q points is freed
int foo = *q; //undefined; the memory to which p points was freed
```

I can understand the explanation above clearly.
BUT, when I come across *Exercise 12.13*, I am a little bit confused.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<memory>
using namespace std;

int main(){
        auto sp = make_shared<int>();
        auto p = sp.get();
        delete p;
        cout <<"Before main function exits!"<<endl;  //which I add for debug
        return 0;
}
```

There is no error in compiling. But an Error goes like below when running

```
***Error in './ex12_13': double free or corruption(out): 0x09b97018***
```

**And the context to debug** *Before main function exits!* **has not been excuted**, which means the error happens just after *delete* operation in my opinion. I also use 'gdb' the debug this program and error pops out just after *delete* indeed.

**SO, how to explain the error?** *Delete* freed the memory already but when does the second free happen? Before main function exits?

---

I changed the initialization of *sp* from *make_shared* function to *new* and 
use my own **deleter** function in place of *delete*.

```
        #include<iostream>
        #include<memory>
        using namespace std;
        int main(){
        auto deleter = [](int*p){
             cout<<"deleter called"<<endl; delete p;
        };
        shared_ptr<int> sp(new int, deleter);
        auto p = sp.get();
        delete p;
        cout <<"Before main function exits!"<<endl;  //which I add for debug
        return 0;
}
```

Then the output turns out to be

```
Before main function exits!
deleter called
***Error in './ex12_13_2': double free or corruption(out): 0x08995998***
```

when the program goes out of main scope, the local variable *shared_ptr p* will be destroyed and the memory *p* points to will be deleted by calling *deleter*.

That's why the ”before main function exits!" shows firstly, the *deleter called* shows later and finally the *double free* error.

So I think the confusion I put forward above is mainly **from make_shared**. @Ben Voigt gives a detailed explanation.

> You are deleting a pointer that didn't come from new, so you have undefined behavior (anything at all can happen).

But the underlying reason maybe could only be found from the implement of *make_shared*.

Comment: I got another error here -- http://ideone.com/eMJMOJ

Comment: @Diego The error you mentioned does not occur on my g++ compiler and it also doesn't occur on this online complier [link]http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/

Answer (score 4):

> when is the second free happens before main function exits?

Actually, it doesn't.  Now, it is entirely possible that your program DOES crash on the `delete p;`, but **not because of a double free**.  You are deleting a pointer that didn't come from `new`, so you have undefined behavior (anything at all can happen).  In particular, `make_shared` is often optimized to minimize allocations by placing the metadata (with the reference count and deleter) and the object in a single allocation.  That allocation could be made using `new[]`, or the resulting object pointer could be in the middle, not the beginning, of the allocation.  In either case, trying to `delete` the object directly (even if releasing the smart pointer to avoid a future second deallocation) will be nothing but trouble.

However, we can't be sure exactly where it is crashing, because your test code has a small flaw.

```
cout <<"Before main function exits!"<<endl;
```

does not display text immediately, it just adds it to the `stdout` buffer.  Because the program crashes, the buffer is never actually written to the associated file descriptor.

For "printf debugging", always use an unbuffered stream such as `cerr`

```
cerr << "Before main function exits!" << endl;
```

then you will see the true order of events.

Comment: [`Inserts a new-line character and flushes the stream.`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/endl/)

Comment: The `flush` manipulator calls `flush()` on the stream. `endl` does that too (after inserting a newline character).

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Maybe buffering outside the iostreams layer, then?  IDEs probably use pipes to capture the output, and that could be buffered also?  In any case, using `stderr` instead of `stdout` avoids any buffering problems.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: I just  made the change, but nothing has changed when executing.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your last paragraph is the answer, and should be brought to the top, instead of being an afterthought.

Comment: Nice observation about there being no call to new for the int stored by the shared pointer.

Comment: One thing to try (and it works for me, i.e. the output shows up, even without a forced flush) is to use the raw pointer constructor for `shared_ptr`, instead of `make_shared`. e.g. `std::shared_ptr<int> sp(new int);`

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Good advice. The results changed and I will update the results later.

Comment: @BenVoigt Thanks a lot for your comprehensive view